# How to get metadata with include_media_info?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

How to get metadata with include_media_info=true via dropbox core api sdk for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Dropbox iOS Core SDK doesn't currently support include_media_info yet, but it is open source so you can modify it to support it. For example, the SDK uses this method to call the HTTP API:

```
- (void)loadMetadata:(NSString*)path withParams:(NSDictionary *)params
```

The documentation for the HTTP endpoint itself can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata).

I haven't implemented and tested this, but at a glance it seems you'd have to implemented a new metadata method that sets include_media_info in the params that it passes to the above method, or just always sets include_media_info if you know your app always needs it. You'd probably also have to update `DBMetadata` to returned the media info.